# Correct my sketch of proof about the convexity of the "natural" power tower on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: inequality, power-towers, convexity-inequality, karamata-inequality

Hi I want to show the following fact :

### Problem :

Let $x\geq 1$ and $n\geq 1$ a natural number and define:

$$f(x)={}^{2n}x=\underbrace{x^{x^{⋰^{x}}}}_{2n\text { times}}$$

Then we have :

$$f''(x)\ge 0$$

---

---

### My sketch of proof for $x\ge y\geq 1$ :

We suppose by induction that $k\geq 2$ a natural number :

$${}^{k-1}x+{}^{k-1}y\geq {}^{k-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)*2$$

Or :

$${}^{k-1}x\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+{}^{k-1}y\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\geq{}^{k-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)*2\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

Now we want show that :

$${}^{k-1}x\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+{}^{k-1}y\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq {}^{k-1}x\ln\left(x\right)+{}^{k-1}y\ln\left(y\right)$$

Or :

$${}^{k-1}x\ln\left(\frac{\frac{x}{y}+1}{2}\right)+{}^{k-1}y\ln\left(\frac{\frac{y}{x}+1}{2}\right)
\ge 0$$

As we have suppose that the function $g(x)=^{2n-1}x$ is convex on the interval $I=[1,\infty)$ (we use Jensen's definition +continuity) next we use Karamata's inequality with $g(x)$ to have the  inequalities :

$$x\ln\left(\frac{\frac{x}{y}+1}{2}\right)\ge 0$$

And

$$x\ln\left(\frac{\frac{x}{y}+1}{2}\right)+y\ln\left(\frac{\frac{y}{x}+1}{2}\right)
\ge 0$$

It works because the function $g$ is also increasing . Conclude by induction . Obviously log convexity implies convexity also .

We are done

> My natural question is :

> > Is my strategy correct ?

> > > Thanks in advance .

Comment: I do not understand the above definition of $f(x)$. What does this notation mean in usual terms ?

Comment: @Peter Good question see Rucker https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html .

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34055/42969 for some better ways to typeset a “left exponent”, for example `{}^{2n}x`

Comment: Shouldn't the induction hypothesis be that ${}^{2n-2}x$ is convex?

Comment: @MartinR Second good question !  No because I use also the convexity in the odd case and because obviously $\ln$ decreases only one exponent . Unfortunetaly it's not the case on the entire interval $(0,1]$ . Thanks for pointing out this kind of ambiguity.:-).

Comment: @MartinR thanks again for the helps see the question edited .

Comment: @MartinR Woopsie thanks !

Comment: @MartinR No problem sir !

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, define recursively $f_n(x)$ by $f_0(x) = 1$ and $f_{n+1}(x) = x^{f_n(x)}$ for every $n \ge 0$. Hence, $f_1(x)=x$, $f_2(x)=x^x$, $f_3(x)=x^{(x^x)}$ and so on.

We prove by recursion that for every $n \ge 0$,
$$\forall x \ge 1,~f_n(x) \ge 1 \text{ and } f_n'(x) \ge 0 \text{ and } f_n''(x) \ge 0.$$
When $n=0$, these large inequalities are equalities.

Let $n \ge 0$ and assume that the inequalities above hold. Then for every $x \ge 1$,
$$f_{n+1}(x) = \exp(f_n(x)\ln x) \ge \exp(0) = 1,$$
$$f_{n+1}'(x) = \Big(f_n'(x)\ln x + f_n(x)\frac{1}{x} \Big) f_{n+1}(x) \ge (0+1) \times 1  = 1 \ge 0,$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{n+1}'(x) 
&=& \Big(f_n''(x)\ln x + 2f_n'(x)\frac{1}{x} - f_n(x)\frac{1}{x^2} \Big) f_{n+1}(x) + \Big(f_n'(x)\ln x + f_n(x)\frac1x \Big) f_{n+1}'(x) \\
&=& \Big(f_n''(x)\ln x + 2\frac{f_n'(x)}{x} - \frac{f_n(x)}{x^2} \Big) f_{n+1}(x) + \Big(f_n'(x)\ln x + \frac{f_n(x)}{x} \Big)^2 f_{n+1}(x) \\
&=& \Big(f_n''(x)\ln x + 2\frac{f_n'(x)}{x} + \frac{f_n(x)^2-f_n(x)}{x^2} + f_n'(x)^2\ln^2 x + 2f_n'(x)\ln x \frac{f_n(x)}{x} \Big) f_{n+1}(x) \\
&\ge& 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows the inequalities for the integer $n+1$.

Hence for every $n \ge 0$, the function $f_n$ is non-decreasing and convex on $[1,+\infty[$.